# Solving the diffusion equation by separation of variables and a series solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, power-series

I am utterly confused by the following question:

[image]

[image]

When you use separation of variables, you get

$U=X(x)T(t)$

$\frac{T'}{T}=\nu \frac{X''}{X}$

This solves nicely to an exponential solution for T: $T(t)=C_\lambda e^{\lambda t}$ and using the suggested series solution for X:

$X''-\frac{\lambda}{\nu}X =0$

$\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty (a_{n+2}(n+1)(n+2)-a_n)x^n = 0$

which gives the form for the coefficients

$a_{2n+1}=\frac{(\lambda/\nu)^n a_1}{(2n+1)!}$

$a_{2n}=\frac{(\lambda/\nu)^n a_0}{(2n)!}$

When $\lambda=0$, you get $T=const$ and $X=bx+c$

The full solution is therefore (where I assume $\lambda$ takes on discrete values not yet found

$U(x,t)=bx+c + \Sigma_{\lambda \neq 0} e^{\lambda t}\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda/\nu)^n a_0 x^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\frac{(\lambda/\nu)^n a_1 x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

So from this I am very confused. It is impossible, if this form is correct, to have a power of $x^2$ in the initial condition without also having all even powers of x.

Would appreciate a hint, or if someone can see one of my assumptions/steps is incorrect.

Comment: where is the coefficient in the series solution ? $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_{n+2}(n+1)(n+2)-a_n)x^n = 0$$

Comment: @Isham Do you mean the coefficient for T? I thought that was taken care of by the coefficients of the x solutions. I should think that would then work with the boundary and initial conditions (determining b,c, and the allowed values of lambda)...

Comment: @Isham In that series the $a_{n+2}$ and $a_n$ are the coefficients

Comment: @Isham. Oh yes, small mistake- I missed out the $\lamda/\nu$ It appears in the final solution however, and it doesn't solve the problem... but thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tried to do an eigenvalue expansion but you haven't found the possible eigenvalues! The method goes like this: *Suppose* that $$T'/T = \nu X''/X = \lambda$$
*then* what can we deduce about $\lambda$? You should observe that the series solution you've obtained is just $X(x) = a_{0}\cos(\omega x) + a_{1}\sin(\omega x)$, where $\omega^{2} = \lambda / \nu$. Well, one of our boundary conditions is $U(0,t) = 0$ so that surely forces $a_{0}=0$. Then we have to have $U(L,t) = 0$ too. But arbitrary choices of $\lambda$ won't make this happen! You get a constraint on the eigenvalues here, and the general solution will be a linear combination of all possible eigensolutions. This gives you enough freedom to express initial conditions like your given one (but cross that bridge when you come to it).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But  now I just have a solution in sine, or fully $ax+\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty a_ne^{-\frac{n^2\pi ^2 \nu t}{L^2}}sin(n\pi x/L}$. I still cannot make an even power of x from this. It is entirely odd!

Comment: Correct, so you'd better expand an odd function! How does $$f(x) = \begin{cases}x^{2} &x \ge 0 \\ -x^{2} &x \le 0\end{cases}$$
sound?

Comment: ! I see- our conditions only specify the form of the function for a certain region, and our solution needs only be valid (i.e. actually represent the physical quantity) in this domain. I do get a solution now for the coefficients

Comment: Glad to hear it!